# How to display data from API as gridview - Kotlin - Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gridview, retrofit

i am trying to display data from API as gridview i tried different ways to do it but it either display it incorrectly or above each other

so what is the correct way to do this?

Here is my code:

Interface:

```
interface facebookInterface {

@GET(" ")

fun getServices(): Call<List<facebookData>>

companion object Factory {
    fun create(): facebookInterface {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("URL")
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(facebookInterface::class.java)
    }
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
class facebookAdapter(var countryList: List<facebookData>,
                  private val facebookAdapterCallback: FacebookAdapterCallback)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<facebookAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
lateinit var context: Context
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): facebookAdapter.ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context!!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.facebook_list_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if(countryList.size > 4) {
        4
    } else {
        countryList.size
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: facebookAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    holder.thumbnailUrl.setOnClickListener {
        facebookAdapterCallback.onFacebookAdapterItemClick(countryList[position])
    }

    Picasso.get()
        .load(countryList[position].imageUrl)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(holder.thumbnailUrl)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val thumbnailUrl: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_img)
}

interface FacebookAdapterCallback{
    fun onFacebookAdapterItemClick(data: facebookData)
}
}
```

facebook_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/list_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:contentPadding="8dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook_img"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

activity:

```
val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_recycler4)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
val facebookInterface = facebookInterface.Factory.create()
val facebok: Call<List<facebookData>> = facebookInterface.getServices()
facebok.enqueue(object : Callback<List<facebookData>> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<facebookData>>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.d("xxxx", t.toString())
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<List<facebookData>>,
        response: Response<List<facebookData>>
    ) {
        Log.d("xxxx", response.body().toString())
        val list = response.body()!!
        recyclerView.adapter = facebookAdapter(list, this@MainActivity)
    }
})
```

data class:

```
data class facebookData (
val  imageUrl : String,
val imageLink: String,
val source: String
)
```

i tried making the XML gridview but it would take the first image only and repeat it in vertical view

do i need to change something in the adapter or XML?

i tried to change "val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_recycler4)" to gridview but i faced some issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by using RecyclerView's GridLayout Manager instead of using Linear Layout Manager.

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
```

where this is the context and 2 is the count of the grid, you can use  3 or other as per your requirements.